# Convert timestamp to date ColdFusion HQL SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, coldfusion, date-conversion

Query example:

```
<cfquery name="jkgh" dbtype="hql">
SELECT COUNT(production_status_id)
FROM production s
where convert(varchar(10),s.production_end,111) = 
'#dateformat(now(),"yyyy/mm/dd")#'
</cfquery>
```

I am trying to convert the 'production_end' timestamp to a date format (any format will do without the time) in order to compare it with today's date.

I have tried all the conversion methods I could find but all so far have given an error.

If this is not possible, then I will have to change the database structure to include two separate fields with date and timestamp... or abandon Hibernate and write an SQL query...

What am I missing?

Comment: Post the error - all of it. And define the datatype of the column product_end.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for your comment, it actually helped me fix the issue. The column datatype was set to VARCHAR ... duh! It's been a long day.

Having said that, the standard conversion in this example still does not work in this way and maybe it can't and that's ok (unless someone can actually how you would do this if it is possible.

Comment: *"...the standard conversion in this example still does not work in this way and maybe it can't..."* It can't work with a varchar column, because the style `111` only applies to datetime columns. For varchar columns it does nothing, and the query likely ends up comparing apples to oranges. For example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00edbcf81af4752bdfc4d97b2ddacd52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where convert(varchar(10),s.production_end,111) = '#dateformat(now(),"yyyy/mm/dd")#'

You shouldn't need to modify the date column. (Also, that type of comparison is generally discouraged because it's not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)). The standard approach for returning rows with today's date is using:

```
WHERE  production_end >= {TodaysDateAtMidnight}
AND    production_end  < {TomorrowsDateAtMidnight}
```

... or in other words

```
WHERE  production_end >= '2022-04-15' -- Today is April 15, 2022
AND    production_end  < '2022-04-16'
```

If you're tempted to use BETWEEN, see:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: I like your solution (although it still throws an error of a different kind) but it isn't answering the fundamental question of why I can not convert the date in the query. This is standard SQL but it does not work in HQL.

Comment: Exactly what error messages are you getting? Could you [edit] the question and include the complete error message, for both the original code - and the above?

Comment: you have helped me a great deal in solving the problem and together with --Smor   comment my issue is fixed. I used 'BETWEEN' instead of the > and < operators but the idea is the same. With the fact that the datatype is now fixed, my problem is solved. I could not convert the date because of the datatype! Thank you.